# Installing Windows 10 on a Samsung 850 EVO SSD gets stuck at "Copying Windows files (0%)"

Tags: windows-10, installation, ssd, uefi

Recently, I acquired a Samsung 850 EVO 120 GB SSD to use for OS (Windows 10) installation. After creating a bootable USB installer (using Rufus) and booting from it, I can do the following things:

1. reach Windows 10 installer screen
2. set my language settings
3. configure partitions (I let Windows manage it)
4. start the installation

The problem is that the installation gets stuck on `Copying Windows files (0%)`. I have tried various formatting of USB installer (GPT, MBR), different USB media (flash sticks, external hard drivers) tried to install Windows 7, 8.1 and 10 but no success. Before trying to install, I have used the Samsung provided tools for setting up the SSD, did a Secure Erase, I have set SATA mode to AHCI, but nothing helped. The diagnostic tools show that SSD is in top shape.

My question is, has anyone seen a similar problem and what could be the solution?

Comment: Can you write files on the SSD, in a format like FAT?

Comment: @FlareCat By FAT do You mean the file system? The SSD is only NTFS formattable (currently inserted the SSD in a laptop as a second drive). But file writing is working without any hiccups or other strange behaviour.

Comment: If it is a used drive and encryption has been enabled on the drive, you will have to contact Samsung for the psid revert tool to clear encryption and start fresh....or see this, this link applies to the 850 series also....http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2366848

Comment: @Moab it is a completely new drive, so no encryption was set on the drive.